# angular ng-repeat hides style of div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using angular ng-repeat to get several divs. The code in original template html is :

```html
<div class="span5 noMarginLeft">

  <div class="dark">

    <h1>Timeline</h1>

    <div class="timeline">
      <div class="timeslot">
        <div class="task">
          <span>
     <span class="type">appointment</span>
          <span class="details">
      Dennis Ji at Bootstrap Metro Dashboard HQ
     </span>
          <span>
      remaining time
      <span class="remaining">
       3h 38m 15s
      </span>
          </span>
          </span>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          3:43 PM
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the style of each div (class: 'timeslot' or 'timeslot alt') is auto-calculated for its height: 
[image]

and the result of the code is: 
[image]

when I use ng-repeat to get these divs, (code here)

```html
<div class="timeslot" ng-repeat="comment in allComments">
  <div class="task">
    <span>
   <span class="type">{{comment.userId}}}</span>
    <span class="details">
    {{comment.content}}
   </span>
    <span>
    <span class="remaining">
     {{comment.dislike}}
    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="time">
    3:43 PM
  </div>

</div>
```

the style of the div is gone, and the height of each div is not auto-calculated. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like auto calculation running before the content is inserted by ng-repeat? How does the auto sizing works? When does it run?

Comment: try to use ng-style or ng-class

Comment: I find it in the custom.js file : if($('.timeline')) {
  
  $('.timeslot').each(function(){
   
   var timeslotHeight = $(this).find('.task').outerHeight();
   $(this).css('height',timeslotHeight);
     
                       });
  
 }

Answer (score 1):

You should create a directive to make the calculation. if you are doing this with jquery then you are going to face same issue.

```
 /**
   * Lets create directive
   */
  angular
    .module('demoApplication')
    .directive('autoHeight', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       //Do your calculations here 
        console.log(element.css('height'));
      }
    };
  }]);
```

HTML

```
 <div class="timeslot" ng-repeat="comment in allComments" auto-height>
  <div class="task">
    <span>
      <span class="type">{{comment.userId}}}</span>
      <span class="details">
        {{comment.content}}
      </span>
      <span>
        <span class="remaining">
          {{comment.dislike}}
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="time">
    3:43 PM
  </div>
</div>
```

[Woring plunker for directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/sc1Paq?p=preview)